# Running a Python REPL in Android

Tags: android, python, read-eval-print-loop

I've installed [QPython](http://qpython.com/) on my Android phone, but there doesn't seem to be a REPL included with the app, just an interpreter that can be fed scripts.  What's the easiest way to get a Python REPL running on an Android phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version off the PlayStore, for both [QPython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus) and [QPython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpy3), have a REPL console.

Comment: Oh, okay, awesome.  Thanks, I hadn't actually checked in a while.  :)

Comment: Hmm so no history or tab completion, huh?  I guess it's theoretically useful :/

Comment: Both links are no longer valid.